# Width of datepicker field?

Tags: datepicker

I'm using the `datepicker` of `dosamigos`.

My code looks something like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Data_entrada')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
        // inline too, not bad
        'language' => 'pt',
        'inline' => false, 
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Escolha a data de entrada ...'],
         // modify template for custom rendering
        //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-   color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'todayHighlight' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        ]
]);?>
```

My input field is long, so I wanted to change the width of the field.

Can you tell me how?

Comment: If I unncoment that line, it doens't show the "calendar button". It does resolve my problem, but it creates an other one!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `width: 250px` CSS class in the style attribute of the div being generated. That would be the place to start.

If I uncomment that line, it doesn't show the "calendar button". It does resolve my problem, but it creates an other one!